# How Can I Countunique from a compring 1 column eith 3 columns?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, match, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MqCEN2IyNagSp9ngzKo6tXfJMyxwRceRXtXsYBQwYfk/edit?usp=sharing) I have tried to find matches between 1 column and 3 columns. It works. Now I want to count the hits BUT if for some reason there is an odd value it still counts.

[image]

I have tried:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(E3:E;{A$3:A;B$3:B;C$3:C};0)))
```

The desired output would be a total count of 3 (Apple, Tomato, Pear) and still 3 missing (Banana, Squash, Cucumber) and unique count = 3 and not 4.

What will I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G3:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER({A3:A;B3:B;C3:C}; 
 REGEXMATCH({A3:A;B3:B;C3:C}; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; E3:E)))))
```

G6:

```
=COUNTA(E3:E)-COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER({A3:A;B3:B;C3:C}; 
 REGEXMATCH({A3:A;B3:B;C3:C}; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; E3:E)))))
```

G11:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER({A3:A;B3:B;C3:C}; 
 REGEXMATCH(LOWER({A3:A;B3:B;C3:C}); LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; E3:E)))))))
```

note `LOWER()` for case insensitivity

Comment: If you don't mind me getting back to this question, please take another look at the formular you provided earlier today: =COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER({A3:A;B3:B;C3:C}; 
 REGEXMATCH({A3:A;B3:B;C3:C}; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; E3:E))))))

It turns out, as always, in real life, users can't be trusted to write excactly. So how do I change the | to (?i) case insensitive?